# How to use multipart in golang

Tags: http, go, curl

I need to generate a multipart post request of this form:

```
POST /blabla HTTP/1.1
Host: 2.2.2.2
Authorization: moreblabla Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--rs0q5Jq0M2Yt08jU534d1q Content-Length: 347
Node: 1.1.1.1.1
--rs0q5Jq0M2Yt08jU534d1q Content-Type: application/json

{"hello" : "world"}
--rs0q5Jq0M2Yt08jU534d1q
```

(if you know how to generate the above with Curl, please give me a tip too ;))
I tried the following:

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`{"hello" : "world"}`)

func main() {

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    part, _:= writer.CreateFormField("")

    part.Write(jsonStr)
    writer.Close()

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "blabla", body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

   ...

}
```

But the server cannot read the content of body. It responds with a 200 HTTP request but it says that the message type is not supported.

So how do I generate a multipart/mixed request that is of the form above?

Thanks kindly in advance for your help.

Comment: You want to generate multipart/mixed but call writer.FormDataContentType() which creates a multipart/form-data: Assemble the Content-Type header yourself using writer.Boundary. Your part is not a form field so you cannot use the convenience function writer.CreateFormFields but you should use writer.CreatePart which lets you set the appropriate Content-Type to application/json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
body := &bytes.Buffer{}
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

part, _ := writer.CreatePart(textproto.MIMEHeader{"Content-Type": {"application/json"}})
part.Write(jsonStr)

writer.Close()

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://1.1.1.1/blabla", body)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary="+writer.Boundary())
```

[Run it on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/szHnUxKm_cM).

Comment: where do you set the boundary here and the path? Also, isn't FormDataContentType incorrect?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right regarding the boundary we and cannot even use a path with multipart/mixed. I didn't read the implementation here properly when I commented https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch.  The content type in OPs question is still multipart/mixed. I created the header *manually* with that content type.

Comment: right, or something like this `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary="+writer.Boundary())`