Getting ATT001.txt file (0 bytes) in attachment as extra attachment while using golang's smtp and multipart
Please check ToBytes() method, that appears to me where problem lies.
package mail

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/smtp"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/personal-mailer/props"
)

type Sender struct {
    auth smtp.Auth
}

type Message struct {
    To          []string
    CC          []string
    BCC         []string
    Subject     string
    Body        string
    Attachments map[string][]byte
}

func New(smtpCred props.SMTPCredentials) *Sender {
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", smtpCred.User, smtpCred.Pass, smtpCred.Host)
    return &Sender{auth}
}

func (s *Sender) Send(m *Message, smtpCred props.SMTPCredentials) error {
    hostAndport := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", smtpCred.Host, smtpCred.Port)
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", smtpCred.User, smtpCred.Pass, smtpCred.Host)
    return smtp.SendMail(hostAndport, auth, "some_email@email.com", m.To, m.ToBytes())
}

func NewMessage(s, b string) *Message {
    return &Message{Subject: s, Body: b, Attachments: make(map[string][]byte)}
}

func (m *Message) AttachFile(filePaths []string) error {
    for _, path := range filePaths {
        b, err := os.ReadFile(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, fileName := filepath.Split(path)
        m.Attachments[fileName] = b
    }

    return nil
}

func (m *Message) ToBytes() []byte {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    withAttachments := len(m.Attachments) > 0
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("From: %s\n", "some_email@email.com"))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\n", m.Subject))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\n", strings.Join(m.To, ",")))
    if len(m.CC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Cc: %s\n", strings.Join(m.CC, ",")))
    }

    if len(m.BCC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Bcc: %s\n", strings.Join(m.BCC, ",")))
    }

    buf.WriteString("MIME-Version: 1.0\n")
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
    boundary := writer.Boundary()
    if withAttachments {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s\n\n", boundary))
        // Add the email body as a part
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))
        buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n")
        buf.WriteString(m.Body)
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n--%s\n", boundary))
        // Add attachments
        for k, v := range m.Attachments {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: %s\n", http.DetectContentType(v)))
            buf.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n")
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"%s\"\n\n", k))

            b := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(v)))
            base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b, v)
            buf.Write(b)
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n--%s\n", boundary))
            buf.WriteString("--\n")
            buf.WriteString("--\n")

        }
    } else {
        buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n")
        buf.WriteString(m.Body)
    }

    return buf.Bytes()
}

code is working though like receiver is receiving mail with attachment if included.
I am trying to play with boundaries to know why this att00001.txt file is being attached but that won't work

One correction -  It won’t send mails to CC emails as not being included in smtp.SendMail method. Hence, to do that need to concat (to and cc) and use it there.

It would be helpful if you would actually document your code with what you've intended so that one can understand if your implementation is just broken or if your understanding of MIME is wrong.
It is obvious thought that the two buf.WriteString("--\n") after each attachment are wrong (unclear what you think they should do) and that the end boundary (after the last MIME part) is missing.
If you want to know more about this see RFC 2046 section 5.1 about the multipart content-type and specifically section 5.1.1 about the role of the boundary.
But, since you are using multipart/mime anyway it would make more sense to use multipart.CreatePart to handle the complicated MIME part and boundary stuff instead of trying to implement MIME headers and boundary properly yourself.

Thanks much !! went through internet standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages
Code is fixed now, incorporating standard format of MIME message.
Although, can you help me with how you're suggesting to use multipart.createPart, that seems logical but i am failing with in respect of implementation

@RajatGoyal: simply create the part in the writer - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105449/how-to-use-multipart-in-golang for an example.

Updated ToBytes() method to use MIME standard format.
Used MIME & stackoverflow-question to solve issue.
some work is still required with how multipart is being used though.
package mail

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/smtp"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "github.com/personal-mailer/props"
)

type Sender struct {
    auth smtp.Auth
}

type Message struct {
    To          []string
    CC          []string
    BCC         []string
    Subject     string
    Body        string
    Attachments map[string][]byte
}

func New(smtpCred props.SMTPCredentials) *Sender {
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", smtpCred.User, smtpCred.Pass, smtpCred.Host)
    return &Sender{auth}
}

func (s *Sender) Send(m *Message, smtpCred props.SMTPCredentials) error {
    hostAndport := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", smtpCred.Host, smtpCred.Port)
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", smtpCred.User, smtpCred.Pass, smtpCred.Host)
    return smtp.SendMail(hostAndport, auth, "some_email@email.com", m.To, m.ToBytes())
}

func NewMessage(s, b string) *Message {
    return &Message{Subject: s, Body: b, Attachments: make(map[string][]byte)}
}

func (m *Message) AttachFile(filePaths []string) error {
    for _, path := range filePaths {
        b, err := os.ReadFile(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, fileName := filepath.Split(path)
        m.Attachments[fileName] = b
    }

    return nil
}

func (m *Message) ToBytes() []byte {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    withAttachments := len(m.Attachments) > 0
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("From: %s\n", "some_email@email.com"))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\n", m.Subject))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\n", strings.Join(m.To, ",")))
    if len(m.CC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Cc: %s\n", strings.Join(m.CC, ",")))
    }

    if len(m.BCC) > 0 {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Bcc: %s\n", strings.Join(m.BCC, ",")))
    }

    buf.WriteString("MIME-Version: 1.0\n")
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)
    boundary := writer.Boundary()
    if withAttachments {
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s\n\n", boundary))

        // Add the email body as a part
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))
        buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n")
        buf.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n")
        buf.WriteString(m.Body)

        // Add attachments
        for k, v := range m.Attachments {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n--%s\n", boundary))
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: %s\n", "application/octet-stream "))
            buf.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n")
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"%s\"\n\n", k))

            b := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(v)))
            base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b, v)
            buf.Write(b)

        }
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n--%s--\n", boundary))

    } else {
        buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n")
        buf.WriteString(m.Body)
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\n--%s--\n", boundary))
    }

    return buf.Bytes()
}

